# how to run surfgpu on opencv with ros?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, cuda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, i want to run surfgpu on opencv with ros.and opencv 2.4.3 have provide the code surfgpu . and i have run surfgpu on windows ok. but i don't know how to config surfgpu on ubuntu 11.10.   and my : ubuntu 11.10 64bit;ros fuerte;gpu:gtx 580;opencv is the default version in fuerte. any usefull massege is gratefull.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62266/how-to-run-surfgpu-on-opencv-with-ros?/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-05-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2013-05-07**:
Is not ros can not use CUDA？ I am confused。but rgbdslam have use siftgpu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as i know, the OpenCV that cames with ROS doesn't have the GPU module. So the first step is to install that and make sure you are linking against the new OpenCV and not the ROS one.

---

Originally posted by [jcc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1962/jcc/) with karma: 200 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1